# How can I convert a .whl to an .egg?

Tags: python

I want to create a `.egg` file from a `.whl`. Is this possible?

I have found answers for doing the opposite (`.whl` from `.egg`) using the wheel package, but I cannot figure out how to properly do the reverse.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Even if you _do_ need to do this, what would you do with, say, a wheel that specifies a CPython ABI version? An egg can't specify that; you have to convert it into an egg for one specific CPython version instead. But which one? The one you're using to run the conversion tool? The one that matches `which python`? One specified in a config file somewhere? (What if that one isn't actually compatible with the wheel?)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [humpty](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humpty), a command-line utility available on PyPI to do exactly that.

For instance

```
humpty -d . publicsuffixlist-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

will generate a `publicsuffixlist-0.2.8-py2.7.egg`.

I wrote *humpty* because I needed to convert a `.whl` to a `.egg`.  The task seemed doable, but I did not find any existing utilities or libraries which did the job.

Note that you can also do the opposite with `Wheel convert` which converts from `.egg` to `.whl`.

Comment: Please, try to avoid link only answers.

Comment: This too doesn't work for me. It returns: Unable to read legacy script metadata, so cannot generate scripts